# which is better module for a storing session in mongodb with mongoose

Tags: session, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

The question in the topic head. I choose between [connect-mongodb](https://github.com/masylum/connect-mongodb) and [connect-mongo](https://github.com/marfalkov/connect-mongo)
What is the most difference?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend the latter - its update dates are much more recent.

There are a lot of abandoned projects for node so its always good to look at file modification dates

Comment: Are there any other modules in addition to these?